# Non toxic low temperature solder

Tags: soldering

Which low temperature (< 350°C) solder can be used to solder a ring?
So non toxic in direct constant contact with skin and overall in domestic environment?

Comment: What is the ring made of?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: @Justin: Cu or Ag

Answer (score 2):

Au/Sn solder should do it.  Available at http://www.indium.com/products/

The eutectic point is 536 deg F, or 280 deg C.  I can't vouch for the biocompatibility for permanent skin contact.  The best source for that would likely be with the compliance officer for whatever standard you're trying to hit, or maybe a phone call to the Indium Corporation.